# Поиск всех результатов в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Данный скрипт выводит первый найденный результат по маске из таблицы table. Как найти и вывести все результаты удовлетворяющие условию?

```
$search=$_POST['search'];

if(is_string($search)){
    clear($search);
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Не соединилось!!!");
    mysql_select_db("Rate") or die("Не найдена БД");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die(' Ошибка поиска строки '.mysql_error());

    $line = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    #Ловим передачу из POST 
    $id=$line['id'];
    $name=$line['name'];
    #Распечатка поиска
    echo "<b>id:</b> ".$id;
    echo "<b>Имя:</b> ".$name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'") or die(' Ошибка поиска строки '.mysql_error());

$i = 0;
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
$id = $line['id'];
$name = $line['name'];
print "Row ".$i.": ".$name." and ".$id."<br>";
}
```

Comment: ... WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'")

:-\

Comment: И что тут не так?)